# Inlined icon links have weird behavior on (some) android devices

Tags: android, html, css, icons, font-awesome

So here is a tiny [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1bjbyqxb/1/) :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
      .navButton {
        font-size:30px;
        height:43px;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
      <a class="navButton" href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a>
      <a class="navButton" href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a>
      <a class="navButton" href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Bla</a>
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Bla</a>
      <a class="navButton" href="#">Bla</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It behaves perfectly fine pretty much everywhere, but on my LG G2 and Galaxy Note 2 phones' native browser (it works fine on the Chrome app), when I press one of the right camera links, it displays a white rectangle which covers about half of the icon on the left of it, as follows (here I touched on the right camera):

[image]

Debugging this issue on chrome://inspect shows absolutely no clue: not a single CSS property of any of the elements changes when the link is pressed. When inspected, the display shows no margin or padding colouring in the elements. Using the developer tools, this white rectangle is spawned when forcing any of the three states. (:active, :hover, :focus)

This looks like... a bug? Even if so, any idea how I could avoid this effect with the same kind of rendering?

Also apparently, it's not actually white overlay, this defect just covers icons with "transparency", as shown in this image with a `background-color: red` on the body:

[image]

Comment: you need to define a fixed width oh the <i>

Comment: Tried [there](http://jsfiddle.net/1bjbyqxb/6/) still have these white squares covering other icons, even when I touch on the text links in the bottom div. But [all text](http://jsfiddle.net/1bjbyqxb/7/) works just fine. Also, it still happens without even using the i's, as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1bjbyqxb/10/)

Comment: Have you tried using a inline-block or block styled span instead? Sorry I have an HTC and it looks fine there so I can't duplicate it

Comment: No worries, your suggestions are very appreciated :) I tried what you did, I used spans instead of i's, spans instead of divs too just in case, still get that white thing popping up. I should check if it's white actually. Let me try this with a red background

Comment: also tweak the anchor css on focus:  a:focus { width:43px; ...experiment with stuff }

Comment: Yeah I've actually been trying this for about a month now on my own project. Just brought up the motivation to finally document it in some way. So in other news: it's not white! So it's basically an erased part of the icon that I see, not an overlay.

Comment: Okay so it's not even links, not even inline that is the problem. I cleaned-up my code all the way down to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1bjbyqxb/30) and I still get the error. So basically when I give a larger font-size to a font-awesome element I get that bug.

Comment: try any of these other font units: pt, em, cm, mm, pc

Comment: Okay, will try. I tried using words, such as `larger`, `x-large`, and it seems to happen when the size reaches 23px or more, either written in pixels or words.

Comment: Tried with em, same issue. Doesn't happen at 1.4em, starts happening at 1.5em (~24px)

Comment: sorry it must be a device thing, i just tried it on a Galaxy Edge and it looks good. Perhaps submit a request to the makers of FA

Comment: Yeah, [I figured I should](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/5796) ;) Thanks for the inspiration though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21466769/1439597) was the problem. As the answer to that question suggests, I managed to fix my issue by overriding the font files' order in my css, in order to put svg file in front:

```
@font-face {
  font-family:'FontAwesome';
  src:url('/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src:url('/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular') format('svg'),url('/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),url('/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),url('/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight:normal;
  font-style:normal;
}
```

If you do override the font in your custom CSS (and not modify the original Fontawesome CSS file, which I see as bad practice due to possible future updates of the framework), make sure to change the files paths to reach them.